# Qual è il senso di "strascichi" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> E proprio in quel periodo ludico, Felice meditò di tacere il rinvenimento della lettera destinata a Visidori senior. Sebbene un'insensatezza di pensiero a tratti lo rodesse, ritenne di fare la scelta giusta evitando l'aguzzarsi di spigoli coi colleghi e il divenire *casus belli* d'inevitabili **strascichi**.

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/strascichio) ho visto che "strascichìo" significa

> Un prolungato strascicare, e il rumore o fruscìo di cosa strascicata

Ho cercato, dunque, quali sono i significati figurati di ["strascicare"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/strascicare/) e ho trovato questo:

> In senso fig.: *s. il lavoro, un lavoro*, tirarlo avanti lentamente e contro voglia; *s. una malattia, una noiosa febbricola*, portarsela addosso per parecchio tempo, senza fare alcuna cura e senza notevoli miglioramenti né peggioramenti; più com., *s. la voce, le parole*, pronunciare con monotona lentezza, prolungando il suono (e analogam. *s. il canto, le note*, ecc.).

Quindi, il significato nel brano sopra citato sarebbe quello di prolongare nel tempo i problemi coi colleghi di lavoro? Oppure questi "strascichi" sarebbero piuttosto contrasti, dissensi con questi colleghi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In questo caso lo si deve intendere come

> Conseguenza negativa, risvolto spiacevole: gli s. dell'influenza, di una lite.

Fonte: [Dizionario Sabatini Colletti](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/strascico.shtml)

Comment: Quindi, il problema è che è "stràscico" e non "strascichìo"? Non so perché sempre cado in questo tipo di trappole.

Comment: No. Si tratta del plurale di "strascico".

Comment: Esatto, @Charo (Nico, non mi è chiaro perché rispondi di no). In altri tempi l'ortografia italiana prevedeva soluzioni come -ii, -ij o -î per i plurali delle parole in -io e situazioni simili, mentre adesso sono quasi scomparse, salvo casi occasionalissimi. A volte si ovvia con un accento (prìncipi/princìpi), ma non sempre le due possibilità hanno accento diverso: oratori (pl. di oratore o oratorio), osservatori (analogo) etc.

Comment: "No" nel senso di "non era come pensavi". Riferito al "problema" avrei dovuto scrivere "sì". Penso comunque che la mia risposta si possa intendere se si vogliono applicare i principi di Grice...

Answer (score 0):

> Conseguenza negativa, risvolto spiacevole: gli s. dell'influenza, di una lite.

Aggiungo qualche parola alla risposta corretta qui sopra. Io intendo con "strascico" una conseguenza più leggera, più sfumata, prolungata nel tempo, rispetto a "conseguenza". Per esempio un'influenza (malattia) potrebbe avere come diretta conseguenza un periodo di riposo o cura e, come strascico, un periodo successivo in cui la persona è sostanzialmente guarita ma ha ancora qualche sintomo o limitazione.

Oppure, in caso di una lite fra due persone, lo strascico sono gli effetti, o il ricordo, irrisolti, della lite. Per esempio Mario può avere una lite con Piero; la conseguenza diretta è che per una settimana Mario e Piero non si parlano; poi magari s'incontrano, si chiariscono e riappacificano, ma lo "strascico" della lite impedisce loro di parlarsi serenamente come prima della lite (come è andata a finire? Che col tempo Mario e Piero si sono dimenticati della lite e tutto è tornato come prima!).

Lo strascico, fisicamente, è la parte o l'appendice di un oggetto che striscia (tocca) sul terreno, o anche la scia che un oggetto lascia quando viene trascinato. Rende bene l'idea di qualche cosa che rimane (la scia), anche quando l'oggetto non c'è più.

Comment: Spiegazione molto accurata!